# Rasterio error RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in reduce return

Tags: python, raster, rasterio, volume

I have extracted a mask from a raster in order to test out multiple volume calculations between QGIS and Python

I'm using rasterio to read in the tiff image and calculate its volume:

```
import rasterio

filename = 'C:/tif_image.tif'

with rasterio.open(filename) as src:
    array = src.read()
    meta = src.meta
    area = meta['transform'][0] ** 2 # Pixel size in X
volumes = array * area
total_volume = volumes.sum()

print(total_volume)
```

However I am getting this error

```
RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in reduce return umr_sum(a, axis, dtype, out, keepdims, initial, where) -inf
```

Is there any way to overcome the inf values? Or why are they are inf when they're exact values in the original raster?

Comment: What is `volumes.dtype` ?  Whatever it is, it's is not large enough to represent the sum of its contents.  Try specifying a larger dtype when calling [`np.sum()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.sum.html#numpy.sum)